# W/SQLite: (28) failed to open

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am new to app development and I am trying to create an app that in short.

there is a tabview with each tab opening different fragment which will hold a different recycler_view that will be populated by results from a different table in a .sqlite file I have put in the asset folder.

but I keep getting an error saying the file can't open.

I don't know how to fix this or what to show that would help somebody with more experience find the fault so here is everything.

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
package com.dummies.finalproject.adapter;

public class AbbreviationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetViewHolder> {
    private Activity activity;
    List<Item> items= Collections.emptyList();
    private OnTapListener onTapListener;

    public AbbreviationsAdapter(Activity activity,List<Item> items){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.items=items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item,viewGroup, false);
        return new SetViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetViewHolder setViewHolder, final int i) {
    setViewHolder.txt_phrase.setText(items.get(i).getPhrase());
    setViewHolder.txt_descrption.setText(items.get(i).getDescription());
    setViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(onTapListener !=null){
            onTapListener.onTapView(i);
        }

    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();

    }
    public void setOnTapListener(OnTapListener onTapListener){
        this.onTapListener=onTapListener;
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
    package com.dummies.finalproject.FragmentActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dummies.finalproject.DatabaseHelper;
import com.dummies.finalproject.Item.Item;
import com.dummies.finalproject.OnTapListener;
import com.dummies.finalproject.R;
import com.dummies.finalproject.adapter.AbbreviationsAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AbbreviationsFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private ArrayList<com.dummies.finalproject.Item.Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<com.dummies.finalproject.Item.Item>();
    private Cursor cursor;
    private AbbreviationsAdapter adapter;
    public AbbreviationsFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
        recyclerView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recyler_view);
        loadDatabase();
        return viewGroup;
    }
    public void loadDatabase(){
        databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        databaseHelper.checkandcopydatabase();
        databaseHelper.openDatabase();
        cursor=databaseHelper.QueryData("SELECT * FROM ABBREVIATIONS");
        if(cursor !=null){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.setPhrase(cursor.getString(1));
                    item.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
                    arrayList.add(item);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
        }
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter= new AbbreviationsAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
        adapter.setOnTapListener(new OnTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTapView(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Click to "+ position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper**:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DBNAME ="DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite";
    private static String DB_PATH ="";
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DBNAME,null,1);
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases";
        this.context = context; }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
    public void checkandcopydatabase(){
        boolean dbExsist= checkdatabase();
        if(dbExsist){
            Log.d("Tag", "Database Exist");
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();}
        try {
            copydatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "try again"); } }
    public boolean checkdatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB=null;
        String myPath=DB_PATH + DBNAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if(checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close(); }
            return checkDB != null; }
    public void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myput = context.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DBNAME;
        OutputStream myOutput= new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=myput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);}
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myput.close();}
    public void openDatabase(){
        String myPath=DB_PATH+DBNAME;
        database=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);}
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(database !=null){
            database.close(); }
        super.close(); }
    public Cursor QueryData(String query){
        return database.rawQuery(query,null);
    }}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36170 of [8201f4e1c5]
    (14) os_unix.c:36170: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databasesDoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite) - 
E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process es.finalproject : Pid (20311) Uid (10189) Euid (10189) Gid (10189) Egid (10189)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databasesDoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite" due to error (2)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10189) st_gid(10189) st_ino(75991)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0 : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(65537)
    (1) Stat of /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(327686)
    (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databasesDoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
    Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
        (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)
    #################################################################
```

If you can help me I would be incredibly grateful.

Update:

I made the following changes:

```
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DBNAME;
```

to

```
String outFileName = DB_PATH + "/" + DBNAME;
```

and am now getting the following error on the Stack Trace:

```
W/SQLiteLog: (28) failed to open "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite" with flag (131074) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
    (28) failed to open "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite" with flag (131072) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36170 of [8201f4e1c5]
    (14) os_unix.c:36170: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite) - 
    (1) Process es.finalproject : Pid (13594) Uid (10191) Euid (10191) Gid (10191) Egid (10191)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite" due to error (2)
    (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases" due to error (2)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10191) st_gid(10191) st_ino(75790)
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0 : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(65537)
    (1) Stat of /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(327686)
    (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
    Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
        (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)
    #################################################################
```

Comment: You should not post code as images, you should copy and paste the actual code and then format it as code. You should also include the stack-trace. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the feedback. I hope I don't sound ignorant but what is a "Stack-trace"?

Comment: This may help [Analyze a stack trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces). The stack trace includes the all important WHERE. Note as your are catching exceptions the real issue may not be the exception causing the failure (it would be just before **Try Again** in the log).

Comment: post your stack trace with error. Hard to understand where failed

Comment: Stack trace added. I hope thats right. thank you all so much for helping, been banging my head over this for the last week.

Comment: look closely on this line again and you will find your problem `'/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databasesDoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite'`

Comment: I made the changes so the path now reads "/data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite" but I am still getting a similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue appears to be a missing separator in the path.

That is it is saying

```
data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databasesDoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite
```

When it should be

```
data/user/0/com.dummies.finalproject/databases/DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite'
```

so try changing

```
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DBNAME;
```

to

```
String outFileName = DB_PATH + "/" + DBNAME;
```

Your second issue is that when the database doesn't exist you then try to get the database (which doesn't exist) as per :-

```
this.getReadableDatabase();
```

The attempt to get, and thus open the database before the copy (which then overwrites the empty database) is generally done in an attempt to get around the databases directory not existing.

I'd suggest a few changes.

1. use the Context's `getDatabase(the_database_name).getPath()` methods to return the full database path as a string. So as long as the_database_name the path will be correct.
2. rather than use the SQliteDatabase openDatabase method to see if the database exists, just check if the file itself exists and if it doesn't then check to see if the parent directory exists and it it doesn't make the directories.
3. Do the check and copy (if needed) when instantiating the Database Helper.

As such you may find the following version of **DatabaseHelper.java**  suitable (tested) :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DBNAME ="DoYouGetMeDoc.sqlite";
    private static String DBPATH;
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DBNAME,null,1);
        DBPATH = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDDED
        this.context = context;
        //<<<<<<<<<< START OF ADDED CODE >>>>>>>>>>
        if (!checkDBFile(DBPATH)) {
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error Copying Database");
            }
        }
        database = this.getWritableDatabase(); //OPEN THE Database
        //<<<<<<<<<< END Of ADDED CODE >>>>>>>>>>
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

    /**
     * Alternantive DB check that checks if the file exists,
     * if not makes the database directory if that does not exist
     * @param dbpath
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDBFile(String dbpath) {
        File db = new File(dbpath);
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myput = context.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DBPATH; //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        OutputStream myOutput= new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=myput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);}
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myput.close();
    }

    public synchronized void close(){
        if(database !=null){
            database.close(); }
        super.close(); }
    public Cursor QueryData(String query){
        return database.rawQuery(query,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made these changes but keep getting similar errors.